# What is this chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

This board is from my truck (a 1996 GMC c1500), and it controls the rear defroster. I am trying to identify the chip on the board that has 5977 written on it. Can anyone here identify it?

Edit: A better picture of both sides of the board. The left one is flipped on the vertical axis, so its easier to line things up.

[image: Rear defrost board]

Comment: Do you happen to have the context around it, e.g. what pins seem to be inputs or output, or which pins connect to a power rail?

Comment: Honestly I've just decided to start reverse engineering this board (it's fascinating to me, that they've managed to create a timed-off push on-push off circuit that deals with vehicle voltage fluctuations, all in this neat little package), and I'm not sure what goes where. I was hoping someone would know.

Comment: I've uploaded a better picture.

Comment: Might be a bespoke chip or it could be a house-numbered 555, hard to tell without tracing more of the circuit out.

Comment: Is the function (expected) just a simple monostable timer? Is the time always the same or does it depend on length of the push? Does second push of the button switch it off?
If it is more than basic monostable circuit (press switches it on for fixed time) then I strongly suspect a custom chip.

Comment: it is push on and push off, from what I can remember, but it is always the same amount of time.

Comment: If it's any help, the function of that tantalum capacitor is to explode suddenly after a random number of years.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a common module across GM cars of that era. Here's an example diagram:

[image]

From here: https://ls1tech.com/forums/general-maintenance-repairs/1253902-rear-defroster-install-need-wiring-diagrams-switch.html

So the IC is a timer. Is it a 555 or similar? Maybe. It could also be a custom IC. Hard to determine without reverse-engineering the board.